# NLTK.word_tokenize splitting word(Slang) on it's own

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize

```
  word_data = 'Why you gotta be so rude'
  nltk_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(word_data)
  print(nltk_tokens)
```

OUTPUT: `['Why', 'you', 'got', 'ta', 'be', 'so', 'rude']`

Can someone explain why `gotta` got split into `got` and `ta`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect its treating it similar to a contraction, e.g. my understanding is it would split "you're" in to the tokens " you " and " 're ".

If you don't want it to split this pseudo-word, you may be able to use `wordpunct_tokenize`, which according to the [docs](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) uses a simpler tokenizing algorithm that just focuses on splitting around whitespace/punctuation.